# Can I work with Git command line if I've checked a project out using Eclipse's EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

...or will I break Eclipse integration? That's what happened when I did corresponding command line changes in Subversion using Subclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. For EGit to notice that you have done something outside of Eclipse you have to refresh the project (or wait a bit if you have automatic refresh enabled in General -> Workspace preferences, which is a good idea anyway).

For example, I sometimes start complicated merges using git on the command line and then resolve the conflicts and commit in Eclipse. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Most of time, you can do a project refresh (F5) in eclipse. It then re-read git/subversion meta information and everything should works fine.